# Facebook login from v2.3 to v2.8 user ID changed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I updated my website's facebook login version from v2.3 to v2.8. With the v2.3 I had this id for my facebook profile (https://www.facebook.com/870521502969350) and with the v2.8 I have different id (https://www.facebook.com/1382401371781358). Both ID brings to my account. I used for testing the v2.8 with fb dev tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and here i see my old ID (870521502969350). How is it possible? how can i get back my old ID? (Users who login on my site again gets new profil because of the new ID thing)

Comment: User ids have become app-scoped with API v2.0 - each app gets to see a different id for the same user. Did you by any chance switch app ids? If you are absolutely sure you didn't, then file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error because of you used the new facebook app_id.
Let's comeback the old id was used on V2.3